# Preload next couple images in a dynamic gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

I've searched and found out solutions to preload images IF I have their file names. However my gallery and images are dynamic so it runs a php echo image url code to call my images.

```
    <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
    <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
    <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="
    <?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" 
    <?php echo $image->size ?> />
    <?php } ?></a>
```

What can I do to preload the next 2 or 3 images in the gallery since I wont be able to give the exact image file for each of my galleries. The only solution I found was to make all the images preload which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hide your images when page load and you can run your preload image function

```
$('#gallery img').hide();
$('#gallery img').each(function(e) {
$(this).delay(500*e).fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Comment: This isn't "preloading" anything. It's just creating a fade in animation.

Comment: The thing is your image loading dynamically, I guess that's the reason. can you post your link?

Comment: Are you directing that towards me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear as to what you're asking, but you can't load a resource without knowing it's path.

Also, I assume $image->size returns the string width="X" height="Y". You'll probably be better off having a height and width property, or store the dimensions in an array.

```
if($image->width) {
    echo 'width="' . $image->width . '"';
}
```